# Regex matching text between two constant strings

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I've got a string like this:

```
Copied file D:\TROLOLO~2\MBF~2\PC\..\..\content\Application Folder\Blabla\FooFoo\bar.bar
```

I'd like to match

```
"D:\TROLOLO~2\MBF~2\PC\..\..\content\Application Folder"
```

Both strings "Copied file" and "Application Folder" are known and constant.

How do I do this? Please also explain the rules you use!

Comment: It's so basic that it doesn't deserve other than a comment : ``re.compile('Copied file *(.+?Application Folder)`` builds the regex and the desired portion of text is captured by group between parens. Documentation suffices to understand the pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
^Copied file (.+?Application Folder)
```

The result you want is in group 1

```
^                   : begining of string
Copied file         : litteral
(                   : start grouping
.+?                 : Any char one or more times non greedy
Application Folder  : litteral
)                   : end grouping
```

Answer (score 2):

how about:

```
 re.findall('(?<=Copied file ).*?Application Folder',s)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative not using a regex:

```
>>> text[12:text.index('Application Folder') + len('Application Folder')]
'D:\\TROLOLO~2\\MBF~2\\PC\\..\\..\\content\\Application Folder'
```